# Custom List component - issues on modules import

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm making a custom List component with a custom empty list message. But refresh and actions are not executed any more. I suspect I do not import properly 'DefaultActions' & 'refreshViewAction', do you see the issue?

I dont understand what is the issue on my imports as I took the 'admin-on-rest' List version, changed imports and customized it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { parse, stringify } from 'query-string';
import { push as pushAction } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Card, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import inflection from 'inflection';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import autoprefixer from 'material-ui/utils/autoprefixer';

import { queryReducer } from 'admin-on-rest';
/*
import queryReducer, {
  SET_SORT,
  SET_PAGE,
  SET_FILTER,
  SORT_DESC,
} from '../../reducer/admin/resource/list/queryReducer';
*/

//import ViewTitle from '../layout/ViewTitle';
import { ViewTitle } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import Title from '../layout/Title';
import { Title } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import DefaultPagination from './Pagination';
import { Pagination as DefaultPagination } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import DefaultActions from './Actions';
// TODO : Bug on ref import here
import { Actions as DefaultActions } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import { crudGetList as crudGetListAction } from '../../actions/dataActions';
import { crudGetList as crudGetListAction } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import { changeListParams as changeListParamsAction } from '../../actions/listActions';
import { changeListParams as changeListParamsAction } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import { refreshView as refreshViewAction } from '../../actions/uiActions';
// TODO : Bug on ref import here
import { refreshView as refreshViewAction } from 'admin-on-rest/lib/actions/uiActions';

//import translate from '../../i18n/translate';
import { translate } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import removeKey from '../../util/removeKey';
import { removeKey } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import defaultTheme from '../defaultTheme';
import { defaultTheme } from 'admin-on-rest';

//import withPermissionsFilteredChildren from '../../auth/withPermissionsFilteredChildren';
import withPermissionsFilteredChildren from 'admin-on-rest/lib/auth/withPermissionsFilteredChildren';

import { LinkToUpload } from './ListActions'

import { WithPermission } from 'admin-on-rest'
import authClient from '../../authClient'

const { SET_SORT,
  SET_PAGE,
  SET_FILTER,
  SORT_DESC, } = queryReducer

const styles = {
  noResults: { padding: 20 },
  header: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
};

/**
 * List page component
 *
 * The <List> component renders the list layout (title, buttons, filters, pagination),
 * and fetches the list of records from the REST API.
 * It then delegates the rendering of the list of records to its child component.
 * Usually, it's a <Datagrid>, responsible for displaying a table with one row for each post.
 *
 * In Redux terms, <List> is a connected component, and <Datagrid> is a dumb component.
 *
 * Props:
 *   - title
 *   - perPage
 *   - sort
 *   - filter (the permanent filter to apply to the query)
 *   - actions
 *   - filters (a React Element used to display the filter form)
 *   - pagination
 *
 * @example
 *     const PostFilter = (props) => (
 *         <Filter {...props}>
 *             <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
 *             <TextInput label="Title" source="title" />
 *         </Filter>
 *     );
 *     export const PostList = (props) => (
 *         <List {...props}
 *             title="List of posts"
 *             sort={{ field: 'published_at' }}
 *             filter={{ is_published: true }}
 *             filters={<PostFilter />}
 *         >
 *             <Datagrid>
 *                 <TextField source="id" />
 *                 <TextField source="title" />
 *                 <EditButton />
 *             </Datagrid>
 *         </List>
 *     );
 */
export class List extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateData();
    if (Object.keys(this.props.query).length > 0) {
      this.props.changeListParams(this.props.resource, this.props.query);
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (
      nextProps.resource !== this.props.resource ||
      nextProps.query.sort !== this.props.query.sort ||
      nextProps.query.order !== this.props.query.order ||
      nextProps.query.page !== this.props.query.page ||
      nextProps.query.filter !== this.props.query.filter
    ) {
      this.updateData(
        Object.keys(nextProps.query).length > 0
          ? nextProps.query
          : nextProps.params
      );
    }
    if (nextProps.version !== this.props.version) {
      this.updateData();
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (
      nextProps.isLoading === this.props.isLoading &&
      nextProps.width === this.props.width &&
      nextProps.version === this.props.version &&
      nextState === this.state
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  getBasePath() {
    return this.props.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '');
  }

  /**
   * Merge list params from 3 different sources:
   *   - the query string
   *   - the params stored in the state (from previous navigation)
   *   - the props passed to the List component
   */
  getQuery() {
    const query =
      Object.keys(this.props.query).length > 0
        ? this.props.query
        : { ...this.props.params };
    if (!query.sort) {
      query.sort = this.props.sort.field;
      query.order = this.props.sort.order;
    }
    if (!query.perPage) {
      query.perPage = this.props.perPage;
    }
    return query;
  }

  updateData(query) {
    const params = query || this.getQuery();
    const { sort, order, page, perPage, filter } = params;
    const pagination = {
      page: parseInt(page, 10),
      perPage: parseInt(perPage, 10),
    };
    const permanentFilter = this.props.filter;
    this.props.crudGetList(
      this.props.resource,
      pagination,
      { field: sort, order },
      { ...filter, ...permanentFilter }
    );
  }

  setSort = sort => this.changeParams({ type: SET_SORT, payload: sort });

  setPage = page => this.changeParams({ type: SET_PAGE, payload: page });

  setFilters = filters =>
    this.changeParams({ type: SET_FILTER, payload: filters });

  showFilter = (filterName, defaultValue) => {
    this.setState({ [filterName]: true });
    if (typeof defaultValue !== 'undefined') {
      this.setFilters({
        ...this.props.filterValues,
        [filterName]: defaultValue,
      });
    }
  };

  hideFilter = filterName => {
    this.setState({ [filterName]: false });
    const newFilters = removeKey(this.props.filterValues, filterName);
    this.setFilters(newFilters);
  };

  changeParams(action) {
    const newParams = queryReducer(this.getQuery(), action);
    this.props.push({
      ...this.props.location,
      search: `?${stringify({
        ...newParams,
        filter: JSON.stringify(newParams.filter),
      })}`,
    });
    this.props.changeListParams(this.props.resource, newParams);
  }

  refresh = () => {
    if (process.env !== 'production') {
      console.warn( // eslint-disable-line
        'Deprecation warning: The preferred way to refresh the List view is to connect your custom button with redux and dispatch the `refreshView` action.'
      );
    }

    this.props.refreshView();
  };

  render() {
    const {
            children,
      filters,
      pagination = <DefaultPagination />,
      actions = <DefaultActions />,
      resource,
      hasCreate,
      title,
      data,
      ids,
      total,
      isLoading,
      translate,
      theme,
      version,
        } = this.props;
    const query = this.getQuery();
    const filterValues = query.filter;
    const basePath = this.getBasePath();

    const resourceName = translate(`resources.${resource}.name`, {
      smart_count: 2,
      _: inflection.humanize(inflection.pluralize(resource)),
    });
    const defaultTitle = translate('aor.page.list', {
      name: `${resourceName}`,
    });
    const titleElement = (
      <Title title={title} defaultTitle={defaultTitle} />
    );
    const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);
    const prefix = autoprefixer(muiTheme);

    return (
      <div className="list-page">
        <Card style={{ opacity: isLoading ? 0.8 : 1 }}>
          <div style={prefix(styles.header)}>
            <ViewTitle title={titleElement} />
            {actions &&
              React.cloneElement(actions, {
                resource,
                filters,
                filterValues,
                basePath,
                hasCreate,
                displayedFilters: this.state,
                showFilter: this.showFilter,
                theme,
                refresh: this.refresh,
              })}
          </div>
          {filters &&
            React.cloneElement(filters, {
              resource,
              hideFilter: this.hideFilter,
              filterValues,
              displayedFilters: this.state,
              setFilters: this.setFilters,
              context: 'form',
            })}
          {isLoading || total > 0 ? (
            <div key={version}>
              {children &&
                React.cloneElement(children, {
                  resource,
                  ids,
                  data,
                  currentSort: {
                    field: query.sort,
                    order: query.order,
                  },
                  basePath,
                  isLoading,
                  setSort: this.setSort,
                })}
              {pagination &&
                React.cloneElement(pagination, {
                  total,
                  page: parseInt(query.page, 10),
                  perPage: parseInt(query.perPage, 10),
                  setPage: this.setPage,
                })}
            </div>
          ) : (
              <CardText style={styles.noResults}>
                You haven't uploaded the workforce database yet.
                <WithPermission value={['admin', 'project-leader']} authClient={authClient} >
                <LinkToUpload _projectId={filterValues._projectId} />
                </WithPermission>
              </CardText>
            )}
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

List.propTypes = {
  // the props you can change
  title: PropTypes.any,
  filter: PropTypes.object,
  filters: PropTypes.element,
  pagination: PropTypes.element,
  actions: PropTypes.element,
  perPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  sort: PropTypes.shape({
    field: PropTypes.string,
    order: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  children: PropTypes.node,
  // the props managed by admin-on-rest
  authClient: PropTypes.func,
  changeListParams: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  crudGetList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
  filterValues: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
  hasCreate: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  ids: PropTypes.array,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  path: PropTypes.string,
  params: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  query: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  resource: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  refreshView: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  total: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  version: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

List.defaultProps = {
  filter: {},
  filterValues: {},
  perPage: 10,
  sort: {
    field: 'id',
    order: SORT_DESC,
  },
  theme: defaultTheme,
};

const getLocationSearch = props => props.location.search;
const getQuery = createSelector(getLocationSearch, locationSearch => {
  const query = parse(locationSearch);
  if (query.filter && typeof query.filter === 'string') {
    query.filter = JSON.parse(query.filter);
  }
  return query;
});

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  const resourceState = state.admin.resources[props.resource];
  return {
    query: getQuery(props),
    params: resourceState.list.params,
    ids: resourceState.list.ids,
    total: resourceState.list.total,
    data: resourceState.data,
    isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0,
    filterValues: resourceState.list.params.filter,
    version: state.admin.ui.viewVersion,
  };
}

const enhance = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    crudGetList: crudGetListAction,
    changeListParams: changeListParamsAction,
    push: pushAction,
    refreshView: refreshViewAction,
  }),
  translate,
  withPermissionsFilteredChildren
);

export default enhance(List);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your imports from `admin-on-rest` on the same line:

`import { ViewTitle, Title, [ALL OTHERS HERE TOO] } from 'admin-on-rest';`